# Embed Power BI File in to Windows Application using local data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We develop a windows application that gets deployed with a SQL Server database to client's sites. On the site they may use SQL Server Express or a better version, depending upon their data needs, most would have Express.

We would like to embed and distribute Power BI files (pbix) in to our application. The Power BI files would connect to the client's own instance of SQL Server to obtain the data. Is this possible? If so, how do we go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very possible to do.

Embedding Power BI reports requires either Power BI Report Server (an enhanced SSRS) or Power BI Portal services. The report is embedded in an IFRAME or other embedded web browser. (They are HTML, CSS and JavaScript.)

Licensing will be a consideration for your project. While the Power BI Desktop client is free, the Power BI Report Server and the hosting of reports from the cloud are not. The users who publish the reports will need a Power BI Pro subscription. If you are looking for a free or inexpensive embedded report solution, this is not it.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedding

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/azure-pbie-what-is-power-bi-embedded

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/